# Pure math courses for physicists: Topology

Tags: mathematical-physics, education, mathematics, topology

I'm in my bachelor in physics. In a couple of weeks I start my last year, and I'm interested in taking some pure math courses. As you see, I like the theoretical point of view, but I don't know if the courses I want to take are useful.

Do you think that a course in topology is useful?

I know that it is used in condensed matter physics, and string theory. Wouldn't it be better to study it from the physical point of view?

Comment: Well, topology is interesting in its own right. I think it is useful.

Comment: Try Bott & Tu's Differential Topology. As an added bonus you will learn about differential forms.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean when you talk about studying topology "from the physical point of view"?

Comment: @MoziburUllah And an even better bonus, you'll learn about spectral sequences which are a real weapon for cohomology calculations, with Bott and Tu's description being one the best of this esoteric subject.

Comment: If you plan to study condensed matter or string theory, having a solid mathematical background in topology is certainly a strong advantage. However if you follow a course in mathematics it may be that they focus on many details on the foundations and only scratch the surface of the things you may be interested in (because they'll have more advanced courses for those). My advice is to ask the professor what topics will be covered and have a general idea of what you want to learn. Some physics oriented books about topology might help you out in this. Check Dubrovin-Novikov-Fomenko and Nakahara.

Comment: @probably_someone: I'm sure Juan can answer for himself, but it's important to note for example that Maxwells equations has a topological and metric component. And wider notions of continuity are pervasive in physics - but I would not call them topological.

Comment: Topology is useful in physics, but I would give higher priority to group theory.

Comment: I had two semesters of topology and at least what I learned had no real direct application to physics. I found courses like abstract algebra/group theory to be better.

Comment: @probably_someone "Topology from the physical point of view" = Labs where you get to eat the donuts after you have done the topological experiments with them?